# Estimating numbers of births and deaths in a birth death process

Tags: probability

Given a birth-death process which ends up with a given population size $m$ after a certain time $t$, I am estimating the size of the population n before this by exponentiating the $Q$ matrix of the corresponding Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC) to find the probabilities of reaching $m$ after time $t$ from various starting points.

After estimating this earlier population size $n$, I want to estimate how many of those $n$ members of that population have survived to be part of the current population of size $m$.

How could I go about making this estimation? Currently I am building a $Q$ matrix for a CTMC with pairs of integers as its state space and using numerical exponentiation - but it seems a bit over the top (not to mention very slow).

Comment: You could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm